# How to integrate $\left(\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\right)\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right)$

Tags: integration

How to integrate

$$\int \left(\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\right)\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right)\,dx$$

Please help as possible...

Thank you

Comment: I am not sure about the third term, what do you mean by 1.1

Comment: I suspect s/he means $$\left(\frac{x^n+1}{n+1}\right)\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right) $$

Comment: Or perhaps $$\left(\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\right)\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right)$$ where the left factor appears to be the "power rule" for integrating $x^n$.

Comment: Both expression separated by dot are in multiply..

Comment: Someone at the level required to ask this *must* know **at least** how to use parentheses to make his mathematical expressions clear.

Comment: @user116434 Is what amWhy said correct?

Comment: Yes prahlad sir, I mean that, I am new user please.. I will learn how to write here in correct way..

Comment: We could create a new game at MSE: **Jeopardy ala MSE**: *Guess that Question!*

Comment: @user116434 so is prahlad's interpretation of the problem correct?

Comment: Oh.. sorry correct is what amWhy posted, please forgive

Comment: @amWhy. This is a pretty good idea !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible hint:

You may follow the method [Differential Binomial](http://planetmath.org/integrationofdifferentialbinomial) to find the proper substitution depending on what the value of $n$ is, Otherwise in all other cases for $n$, the integral of a differential binomial cannot be expressed by elementary functions. See [this](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Chebyshev_theorem_on_the_integration_of_binomial_differentials).

Comment: Thank you , information is enough to get answer